# How to add property and value from loadCsv

Tags: neo4j

I have csv with header like :
string,alias,source

I was trying to use query like this :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM file  AS line WITH line 
Match (p{name:SUBSTRING(line.string ,7)})
Create (p:line.source:line.alias)
```

but I get error about last line. Is it possible to add new property to exsisting node using loadCsv ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the SET command. CREATE is reserved for nodes, relationships, and patterns.

You may want to review the documentation or the [Cypher reference](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/).

Also your match doesn't seem to be using a label (you're only using the variable p). If at all possible, use labels in your graph, without them you can't take advantage of your indexes or unique constraints, and even without those, it ensures that you're only scanning over nodes of that label instead of your entire graph.